# Why CycloConverter circuits are used as heavy duty drives for high power applications?

Tags: power-electronics, induction-motor

is it due to the high power applications being slow at their functionality ? i know that CycloConverters can only lower the voltage/frequency of the source , and by that it will reduce the speed of the Induction Motor while keeping the torque constant. But why did we choose the CycloConverters specifically for High power applications and not other power electronic drives ?   Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cyclo-converter power circuits can be designed to use thyristors (silicon controlled rectifiers). The control logic can be designed to use discrete transistors rather than integrated circuits or microprocessors. Thyristors were available at an earlier date with higher current and voltage ratings than transistors. That made it possible 40 to 50 years ago to design AC motor speed controls for voltages higher than 600 volts and currents higher than 500 amps allowing electronic speed control of motors rated above 500 horsepower (370 kW). As technology advanced, other power electronic drive designed have been used at all power levels. However, cyclo-converters are less complex and perhaps less expensive, so they may still be used to some extent.

Comment: They biggest drawback a cycloconverter has is the special-made transformer needed. It's big because of 50/60Hz and it has to be designed for the drive.